How to get metaobject entries in shopify product variations?
I want to create shape variations with images for the products.
For this, I have created a metaobject, and it's not showing in the product admin page. How can this work?
I have created a metaobjects for shapes I'm not able to add images in Shopify. Here is the screenshot: https://prnt.sc/rPK0IawR_xNp
I want that the metafields entries dynamically on the product variations here: https://prnt.sc/NJLiCDXETUqh
